# How do I add the contents of a string?

Tags: string, haskell

Im am making a function which compares two strings to see if one is a rearrangement of the other. for example "hhe" and "heh" would produce true but "hhe" and "hee" would be false. I thought I could do this by summing the elements of the string and seeing if they are the same. I am knew to haskell, so I dont know if I can sum chars like in C. Code so far:

```
comp :: String -> String-> Bool
comp x y = (sum x) == (sum y)
```

This produces an error when compiling.

Comment: Your approach will not work, since this method will yield more "equal" string then there are. If you assign a number to each char (e.g. a = 1, b = 2, ...) then "ab" = 3 as is "c". It will be easiest to count the number for each char and check if both strings have the same amount of occurences IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first sort, then compare the strings

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

comp = (==) `on` sort
```

which can then be used like this

```
"abcd" `comp` "dcba" --yields True
```

Comment: This is a better alternative.

Comment: @Arthur May I ask why?

Comment: @Arthur- @Jefffrey beat me to it....  Is there a reason why?  If I had to do this myself without modules, I would just rewrite `sort` and `on` by hand, and I can do that for you, but it seems like a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: @Arthur Also, you are implicitly importing `Prelude` that defines `sum` and `(==)`. I guess you'll have to write those too.

Comment: @Arthur- Well, there are easier ways to solve this, but there will be a performance hit....  The sort method is O(N*log N), so if you don't mind writing `sort`, that is what I would do.  You could do something where you iterate though items in string1, and pull them out of string2 if they exist (return false otherwise).  At worst case this would be O(N^2), although if you have permutations with just a few relatively local switches, this could actually be faster.  Since it is homework, I'll leave it to you to decide, but I think these would be your choices.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to "sum" two strings. Use `permutations` instead:

```
comp :: String -> String -> Bool
comp x = (`elem` permutations x)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0488bbfd7eb467ff)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it without importing modules

Comment: you can always implement all functions you don't want to import :D

Comment: Well, I say good luck with doing anything in Haskell without importing modules.

Comment: @utdemir Actually he might not even be able to make a compilable program without `IO` which is imported by `Prelude` IIRC.

Comment: @Jefffrey That's being a bit pedantic, I'm sure he means that he doesn't want to use anything outside of `Prelude`.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are problems with your implementation, as suggested by others, the direct answer to your question is that you can first convert characters to `Int` (a type that supports arithmetic) with `fromEnum`.

```
> sum . map fromEnum $ "heh"
309
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example code at face value, the problem with it is that `Char` doesn't implement `Num`, so `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a` is incompatible.

We can fix that, however, by using `fromEnum` to convert the `Char`s to `Int`s:

```
isPermutationOf :: String -> String-> Bool
isPermutationOf x y = hash x == hash y
  where hash = sum . map fromEnum
```

And this will work on your example case:

```
λ isPermutationOf "hhe" "heh"
True
```

The downside is that it also has some false positives:

```
λ isPermutationOf "AAA" "ab"
True
```

We can try to reduce those somewhat by making sure that the lengths, maxes, and mins of the inputs are the same:

```
isPermutationOf :: String -> String-> Bool
isPermutationOf x y = hash x == hash y && maximum x == maximum y && minimum x == minimum y
  where hash = sum . map fromEnum
```

But though that catches some cases

```
λ isPermutationOf "AAA" "ab"
False
```

It doesn't catch them all

```
λ isPermutationOf "abyz" "acxz"
True
```

To do that, we really need to make sure we've got the same number of each `Char` in both inputs.  We could solve this by using a `Data.Map.Map` to store the counts of each `Char` or by using `Data.List.sort` to sort each of the inputs, but if we only want to use the `Prelude`, we'll need to roll our own solution.

There's [any number of examples on how to write `quicksort` in haskell out there](http://bit.ly/1BRy85M), so I'm not going to tell you how to do that.  So here's a dumb `isPermutationOf` that uses math instead.

```
isPermutationOf xs ys = all (\k -> powsum k as == powsum k bs) [0..n]
  where as = map fromEnum xs
        bs = map fromEnum ys
        n = length xs
        powsum k zs = sum (map (^k) zs)
```

Basically, we can view an `n`-length string as a set of `n` unknowns.  `isPermutationOf` checks the `n+1` equations:

- eq<sub>0</sub>: x<sub>0</sub><sup>0</sup> + x<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup> + ... + x<sub>n-1</sub><sup>0</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>0</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup> + ... + y<sub>m-1</sub><sup>0</sup>
- eq<sub>1</sub>: x<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> + x<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> + ... + x<sub>n-1</sub><sup>1</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> + ... + y<sub>m-1</sub><sup>1</sup>
- eq<sub>2</sub>: x<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + y<sub>m-1</sub><sup>2</sup>
- ...
- eq<sub>n</sub>: x<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> + x<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + ... + x<sub>n-1</sub><sup>n</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + ... + y<sub>m-1</sub><sup>n</sup>

`eq0` is essentially a length check. Given `xs`, the other `n` equations work out to `n` equations for `n` unknowns, which will give us a solution for `ys` unique up to permutation.

But really, you should use a (bucket) sort instead, because the above algorithm is `O(n^2)`, which is **slow** for this kind of check.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use standard library(learning purpose) function, you can quickSort both string and check for equality of string (bonus: quickSort)

```
isEqual :: String -> String -> Bool
isEqual a b = sortString a == sortString b
          where
               sortString :: String -> String 
               sortString [] = []
               sortString (x:xs) = sortString (filter (<x) xs) ++ [x] ++ sortString (filter (>=x) xs)
```